# Getting m2eclipse to match maven's classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I've got project with a few sub modules.

```
mvn clean install
```

works absolutely fine. But in Eclipse with the parent project open none of the maven dependencies are available and so all my Java source files are full of indicated compilation errors (they're not listed in the build path for the project). If I open one of the sub modules as a project there are no indicated compilation problems.

I've tried running

```
mvn clean install eclipse:clean eclipse:m2eclipsemvn clean install eclipse:clean eclipse:m2eclipse
```

and choosing project / update maven dependencies. Refreshing, closing and opening the project and Eclipse, etc.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Getting m2eclipse to match maven's classpath

Just use **Import... > Existing Maven Projects** and import your multi-modules Maven project, that's all.

> But in Eclipse with the parent project open none of the maven dependencies are available and so all my Java source files are full of indicated compilation errors (they're not listed in the build path for the project).

A parent project (i.e. with a `pom` packaging) is not a Java project, it's just there as a facility to make editing the parent `pom.xml` from the IDE possible (and that's already nice, importing nested projects inside Eclipse was initially not even possible).

> If I open one of the sub modules as a project there are no indicated compilation problems.

That's how you are supposed to do things.

> I've tried running (...)

You are **not** supposed to use the Maven Eclipse Plugin when using m2eclipse and [this is not supported](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Preparing-for-M2Eclipse-1-0-no-support-for-the-maven-eclipse-plugin-td139921.html). Either use one or the other. If you decide to use m2eclipse, use **Import... > Existing Maven Projects** as suggested.

Comment: That's a shame, but it clears a few things up for me, so thanks.